# nginx SSL and reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have nginx setup with SSL and have defined a proxy_pass directive
so that it proxies certain requests to the backed system through HTTP
What I am interested in knowing is if the response from the backend server will arrive encrypted to the client. 
Will nginx encrypt the response before sending it back to the client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nginx will encrypt the response before it gets sent back to the client. `proxy_pass` happens transparently for the user.